# Creating context menu items for Windows 7 e.g. Scan With

Tags: windows, scripting, registry

Although this is a little broad how is it possible to create a context menu item that a selected file can be used against e.g. like antiviruses to "Scan this file with xxxxxx"

I have a registry file below, although it only lets me simply launch the file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Scan with...]
"Icon"="C:\\app.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Scan with...\command]
@="C:\\app.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

The articles linker will give you a good overview of the options and how to achieve them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144169(VS.85).aspx

Martyn